# Understanding of pumping lemma

Tags: computability

It seems like I missed something in **pumping lemma**. Please, help me out

Let's take the simple example from Sipser's book

Prove that language $L = \{0^n1^n | n>=0 \}$ is nonregular. Following the pumping lemma, we choose $s$ to be the string $0^p1^p$, split $s$ into three pieces $s=xyz$ and consider three cases

1) $y$ consists of 0s. (contradiction is understood). **OK!**

2) $y$ consists of 1s. (contadiction is understood). **OK!**

3) $y$ consist of both 0s and 1s. *"In this case the string xyyz may have the same number of 0s and 1s, but they will be out of order with some 1s before 0s"*
(but wait a second, we can restrict the order only to allowed one, not understood). **not OK!**

The same proof can be taken from wikipedia with different explanation

[wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages)

*"By the pumping lemma, there must be some decomposition w = xyz with |xy| ≤ p and |y| ≥ 1 such that $xy^iz$ in L for every i ≥ 0. Using |xy| ≤ p, we know y only consists of instances of a"*

(but why only a, completely not understood ). **not OK!**

Please, all I need is just a hist, what I've missed

Thanks!

Comment: The reason why you only get instances of 0 this case is because you picked the string $0^p1^p$, where p is your pumping length, then you can use $|xy| \leq p$, which implies that y can only be one or more 0's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:  We have strings $x$, $y$, $z$, with $y$ of positive length, such that $xyz$, $xyyz$, $xyyyz$, and so on are in the language.

If $y$ consists of all $0$'s, there will be "unbalanced" words in the language (too many $0$'s).  But in the language, every word has equal numbers of $0$'s and $1$'s. (This part you understood.)

The same argument applies if $y$ has $1$'s only.

Suppose now that $y$ is "mixed," worst case is something like $y=000111$. (This is worst because if the number of $0$'s in $y$ was greater than the number of $1$'s, then $xyyz$ would have too many $0$'s.  But actually the argument below doesn't depend on whether $y$ is balanced.)

If $y=000111$, then $x000111000111z$ will be in the language.  That's a contradiction, for in 
$$x000111000111z$$ 
the $0$'s do not *all* precede the $1$'s. The $0$ after the first $111$ is to the *right* of a $1$. (In any expression of shape $0^n1^n$, all the $0$'s are to the *left* of every $1$, no $0$ is ever to the right of a $1$.)

Comment: your example it's OK! But if you take y=01, it works accordingly to the shape

Comment: The choice $y=01$ also gives a contradiction, for then $x0101z$ will be in the language, and this has a $0$ to the right of a $1$, just like in my $y=000111$.

Comment: but why it contradicts, it looks exactly as pattern looks 01

Comment: The language $0^n1^n$ means empty word, also $01$, also $0011$, also $000111$, also $00001111$, and so on and **that's all**.  So for example $0101$ is not in the language.  If we want empty word, also $01$, also $0101$, also $010101$, and so on, we write $(01)^n$. That's very different from $0^n1^n$.  Your difficulty has to do with the fact that you are misinterpreting the meaning of $0^n1^n$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! Now everything became clear.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out the reason for your doubts!  It is very important to know what the shortcut symbolism *means*.